# libc segfaults while compiling dev-lang/yasm

Tags: linux, gentoo, segmentation-fault, funtoo

I am trying to compile dev-lang/yasm inside a funtoo chroot and consistently get segfaults.  Any ideas what I should try:

```
[Fri Jan  1 14:54:33 2016] re2c[14786]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f5ad4d4dd5b sp 00007ffe0c08b8c0 error 4 in libc-2.20.so[7f5ad4ce4000+193000]
```

I am compiling on Fedora 23 as the libraries there seem to be a little more stable than the unstable versions on my other funtoo installation.  I checked my mount points and permissions and everything is congruent with the gentoo and funtoo installation documents.

Thanks,

Walter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it was a permissions issue on a hardened box.  I was extracting some configuration files via tar and overwrote the permissions on some directories hence creating the problem.